# How can I use complex filters by protocol in tcpdump?

Tags: wireshark, tcpdump, packet-analyzer

I can filter by lots of protocols in `wireshark` and `tshark`, like this:

`sudo tshark -i <My_Interface> -Y '(ip.addr == <My_IP> and isakmp)'`

How can I add the protocol filter in a `tcpdump` command like this?

`sudo tcpdump -i any -nn host <My_IP>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use filters on the end. These are called Berklee Packet Filters or BPFs for short. In your example, you could do it this way:

`tcpdump -nn -vvv -e -s 0 -X -c 100 -i eth0 host 1.2.3.4 and \(proto 17 and port 500\)`

This would capture traffic to **or** from 1.2.3.4 with Layer-3 protocol 17 (UDP) **and** Layer-4 port 500. You can also use friendly names if they are present in `/etc/protocols` and `/etc/services` like this:

`host 1.2.3.4 and \(proto udp and port isakmp\)`

There are quite a lot more BPFs you can use to limit things like protocol versions to only capture IPv6 (`ip6`) or capture traffic that has the SYN flag set in a TCP packet (`tcp[tcpflags] == tcp-syn`).

If you need a live tool, I've created https://tcpdump101.com which will let you build your tcpdump syntax and BPF so you can just copy and paste it. Hopefully it will help you out.

Comment: Why is the protocol name being treated has port?

Comment: It's not. The way it works is that protocols run on Layer-3 (see: https://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.xhtml) and ports run on Layer-4 (see: https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml). Layer-3 protocol 17 (IP/17) is UDP. Layer-4 port 500 (UDP/500) is "isakmp".

Answer (score 0):

I could create my own filter after some workarounds:

```
whileIFS= read -r line; do if [[ $line =~ 'isakmp' ]]; then echo $line; fi; done < <(sudo tcpdump -i any -nn host <My_IP>)
```